# RoR 4 not pushing to heroku properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Somewhat new to coding and just pushed my site to heroku. I've done it before with no problems, but now it's giving me the "We're sorry, but something went wrong." whenever I try and go to the live site.
I ran heroku logs --tail and this is what it is giving me.

```
  ←[36m2014-03-01T02:16:42.201339+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ):
  ←[36m2014-03-01T02:16:42.201152+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
  ←[36m2014-03-01T02:16:42.201152+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
  ←[36m2014-03-01T02:16:42.200792+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
```

later on I see this

```
←[36m2014-03-01T02:16:42.201734+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
←[36m2014-03-01T02:16:42.201152+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template pages/opening, application/opening with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :build
er, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  ←[36m2014-03-01T02:16:42.201921+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run__2841248799560977586__process_action__callbacks'
```

I've never seen this error and am pretty confused. Let me know what else I should post here. Here's my git hub page https://github.com/Thefoodie/PupPics

Comment: You're haven't pushed the `pages/opening` template, as the warning indicates.

Comment: I suppose I should be more specific. How do I push just the pages/opening template? I've pushed the entire file, and it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

**Error**

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template pages/opening, application/opening with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :build er, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
```

This is standard `view is missing` error - basically means the `/views/pages/opening.html.erb` file has not been uploaded:

1. Make sure you have a file at `/views/pages/opening.html.erb`
2. Make sure you've added & committed the file to git:

   - `git add .`
   - `git commit -a -m "Opening"`
   - `git push heroku master`

---

[**Exception Notification**](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification)

There's an excellent gem you can use called [exception notification](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification):

> The Exception Notification gem provides a set of notifiers for sending
>   notifications when errors occur in a Rack/Rails application

If you install it like this, you'll be able to receive the error messages direct to your email inbox. Here's how you set it up:

```
#GemFile
gem "exception_notification", "~> 4.0.1"

#config/environments/production.rb
Whatever::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
  :email => {
    :email_prefix => "[Whatever] ",
    :sender_address => %{"notifier" <notifier@your_domain.com>},
    :exception_recipients => %w{you@domain.com}
}
```

You then need to get email working, preferably with a third-party SMTP platform such as [SendGrid](https://addons.heroku.com/sendgrid) or [Mandrill](https://addons.heroku.com/mandrill):

```
#config/environments/production.rb
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port           => "25",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => ENV['SENDGRID_DOMAIN']
}
```